# Connect markers with a polyline in Mapbox GL

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I'm developing a web application using Mapbox GL, more specifically, its binding for React, `react-map-gl`.

One of the planned functionalities for the app is adding markers and connecting them.

However, I'm having trouble connecting markers.

I want to start drawing the line when I click on a marker, add a breakpoint to the line when I click elsewhere and finish the line when I click on another marker.

What can I use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using an `EditableGeoJsonLayer` with the features for both the markers and the connections between them as follows:

```
data: {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: markers.flatMap((marker) => {
        // Map markers
        let features = [
            {
                geometry: {
                    type: "Point",
                    coordinates: marker.coordinates
                },
                type: "Feature",
                node: marker
            }
        ];

        // Map connections
        if (marker.connections.length > 0) {
            features = features.concat(
                marker.connections.flatMap((endMarker) => [
                    {
                        geometry: {
                            type: "LineString",
                            coordinates: [
                                marker.coordinates,
                                endMarker.coordinates
                            ]
                        },
                        type: "Feature"
                    }
                ])
            );
        }

        return features;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on same, you can use deck.gl for plotting lines on map, or you can also use geoJson for the same.